# Why is this inter-process communication working?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

In Python, exchanging objects between processes is well documented: queues, pipes or pools should be used (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)). So why is this super simple code working without any of these communication tools?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
from random import random

class Child_process(Process):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Child_process,self).__init__()
    self._memory = {'a':1}

  def writeInMemory(self,key,value):
    self._memory[key]=value

  def readFromMemory(self,key):
    return self._memory[key]

  def run(self):
    while True:
      sleep(random())

def main():
  # start up the child process:
  child = Child_process()
  child.daemon=True
  child.start()
  print 'Type Ctrl C to stop'
  while True:
    print "in sub process a = ", child.readFromMemory('a')
    child.writeInMemory('b',random())
    print "in sub process b = ", child.readFromMemory('b')
    sleep(5*random())
  # exiting
  child.terminate()
  child.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Result is

```
Type Ctrl C to stop
in sub process a =  1
in sub process b =  0.469400505093
in sub process a =  1
in sub process b =  0.43154478374
in sub process a =  1
in sub process b =  0.519863589476
```

Comment: As far as I see you are initiating only one child process. You are printing "In sub-process a/b" in a while loop which is running in main method. I don't see any inter-process communication.

Comment: OK. I understand now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That's because **no** interprocess communication is happening.

Modify the code to print the value of `_memory` in the child process:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        print('Memory is', self._memory)
        sleep(random())
```

And you'll see that the memory inside the subprocess never changes.

A sample output is:

```
Type Ctrl C to stop
in sub process a =  1
in sub process b =  0.571476878791
('memory', {'a': 1})
('memory', {'a': 1})
('memory', {'a': 1})
('memory', {'a': 1})
in sub process a =  1
in sub process b =  0.0574249557159
('memory', {'a': 1})
('memory', {'a': 1})
```

Note how it always prints:

```
('memory', {'a':1})
```

instead of, say:

```
('memory', {'a': 1, 'b': 0.0574249557159})
```

So what is happening is that all your calls are *local*. you are spawning a subprocess that does nothing and you aren't performing any communication with it. The subprocess when is spawned *copies* the `_memory` attribute but that attribute is then never modified, and your changes in the main process do not affect the child process.

---

To be dead clear: you are basically wasting a subprocess. You are spawning one without making *any* use out of it, and after spawning it you are treating your `child` exactly as any other python object.

Comment: Do you mean that self._memory in child  is different from child._memory in main process?

Comment: @user3650925 Yes. When you call `start()` this starts the subprocess which basically **copies** the memory of the current process and then executes the code of the `run` method (in the subprocess). Note that the behaviour can be different between Windows and Linux/Os X due to how they handle subprocesses...

Comment: Should my question title be changed in order not to confuse others ?